# PID expressed as finite union of subrings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

There is a classical theorem that [no field can be expressed as finite union of proper subfields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39605/).

In contrast, there is an [example](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm7/cm717.pdf) of an integral domain that can be expressed as finite union of proper subrings.

Therefore, I wonder whether there are any known results about the existence of Principal ideal domain (or even Euclidean domain) that can be expressed as finite union of proper subrings?

Comment: The example you link to – is it known that it's never a principal ideal domain?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That example is not integrally closed: $D^{1/3}$ is in the fraction field but not in the ring.

Comment: Consider the PID $R=\mathbb{F}_2[t]$. Given a $1$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$-subspace $V \subseteq \mathbb{F}_2^2$, let $R_V=\{f\in R: (f(0),f(1))\in V\}$. Then $R=\bigcup_V R_V$, where $V$ ranges over the $1$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^2_2$.

Comment: Actually, $R_V$ is not a ring since $1\notin R_V$ if $(1,1)\notin V$. Sorry. This question is more tricky than it seems. However, if $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ can be expressed as a union of proper subrings for some $n$, then this should give the required example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the following subrings of $\mathbb{F}_2^3$:
$$
V_1=\{(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(1,0,0),(0,1,1)\}\\
V_2=\{(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,1)\}\\
V_3=\{(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(0,0,1),(1,1,0)\}
$$
Then $\mathbb{F}_2^3=V_1\cup V_1\cup V_3$.

Let $R$ be a PID admitting $3$ distinct surjective ring maps $f_1,f_2,f_3$ onto $\mathbb{F}_2$
and write
$$
R_i=\{a\in R: (f_1(a),f_2(a),f_3(a))\in V_i\}
$$
for $i=1,2,3$.
Then $R_1,R_2,R_3$ are subrings of $R$ with $R=R_1\cup R_2\cup R_3$. They are proper subrings by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

To construct such $R$, take a cubic extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ in which $2$ splits into a product of $3$ primes $P_1,P_2,P_3$,  and choose $R$ to be the localization of $\mathcal{O}_K$ at the multiplicative set $R\setminus(P_1\cup P_2\cup P_3)$.

Comment: The existence of $R$ can also be shown using a theorem of Heitmann. See this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56513/exotic-principal-ideal-domains/56526#56526

Comment: Sorry for accepting the answer after such a long time as it‘s not so obvious to me to prove the existence of such $3$ distinct surjective ring homomorphisms from $R$ onto $\mathbb{F}_2$. Besides, for the 'Euclidean Domain' part, may I ask whether it can be expressed as finite union of proper subrings?

Comment: @SteveJacob No problem. I agree that it is not easy to write down an explicit example. Concerning your question about a Euclidean example, every semilocal PID, e.g., as in the end of my answer, is Euclidean. Indeed, if $P_1,\dots,P_t$ are the nonzero prime ideals in $R$, then the sum of their corresponding additive valuations is a Euclidean function on $R$ (so says Wikipedia).